# I want to improve my kick command in discord.py

Tags: discord.py, command, bots

I have made a bot in discord.py which has a kick command. But I want the bot to say "please tell me whom to kick" when someone uses the command without saying whom to kick. I mean if someone uses the kick command without mentioning whom to kick, the bot will say "please tell me whom to kick".
I am trying to make a good bot so please help me.

````
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if (ctx.message.author.permissions_in(ctx.message.channel).kick_members):
        await member.kick(reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has successfully been kickded for {reason}")
    if not (ctx.message.author.permissions_in(ctx.message.channel).kick_members):
        await ctx.send("You don't perms to play football with Araforce and kick them. Sed")
    if not user:
        await ctx.message.delete()
        msg = await ctx.send("You are a bit idiot, don't you know I can't kick anyone if you don't tell whom to kick? Tell me whom to kick and the go away.")
        await sleep(4.7)
        await msg.delete()
        return
    if not reason:
        await ctx.message.delete()
        msg2 = await ctx.send("Hmm.. Why I will kick him? Specify a reason please.")
        await sleep(4.7)
        await msg2.delete()
        return```
````

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have so far.

Comment: You can try using error handlers

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.User = None, *, reason=None):
    if not user:
        await ctx.message.delete()
        msg = await ctx.send("You must specify a user.")
        await sleep(4.7)
        await msg.delete()
        return
    if not reason:
        await ctx.message.delete()
        msg2 = await ctx.send("You must specify a reason.")
        await sleep(4.7)
        await msg2.delete()
        return
```

Comment: Sorry man but this isn't working

Comment: It does work. I'm using this for my bot which moderates a lot of people. Can you show me your code?

Answer (score 0):

I changed `ifs` to the error handler, which is necessary because if you won't pass one of the arguments (user or reason) you would get an error.

### Full code:

```py
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason): #if you will change "member" and "reason" to something else remember to also change it in error handler
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has successfully been kicked for {reason}")

@kick.error #cool mini error handler
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument):
        if str(error) == "member is a required argument that is missing.": #change this if you changed "member"
            await ctx.message.delete()
            await ctx.send("You are a bit idiot, don't you know I can't kick anyone if you don't tell whom to kick? Tell me whom to kick and then go away.", delete_after=4.7) #you don't have to use "await sleep" you can use "delete_after" parameter
        elif str(error) == "reason is a required argument that is missing.": #change this if you changed "reason"
            await ctx.message.delete()
            await ctx.send("Hmm.. Why I will kick him? Specify a reason please.", delete_after=4.7)
    elif isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You don't have perms to play football with Araforce and kick them. Sed")
```

[Discord error handling example](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling)